# Accessing an iFrame's redirect location on a different port

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, iframe, proxy

I'm building 3D-secure payment gateway but seem to be having trouble with iframes provided both by the 3rd party service provider as well as the previous developer.

A user enters their card details at our site (let's call this "domain.com") which is running on port 443 and https. The information is then passed to a 3rd party iframe where 3d secure card processing is done, it does a few cross origin redirects and then redirects back to our domain (let's call this payments.domain.com) which runs on a completely separate port, 9443. This was not implemented nor is it controlled by me. I'd need to grab a few parameters to verify card details from this redirected URL.

I've successfully managed to submit a form to the iframe, get an OTP from my bank, but where I fall flat is with the catching of the iFrame redirect url. I can see the cross origin redirects and even get a response (albeit a 401) from our domain.

I've tried hooking into the iFrame element's contentWindow.location.href but I get an undefined value. I'm also unable to use postMessages as I don't control the site where the redirect comes from. I've considered proxying the iFrame but I have no idea where to start.

Please help!